# yum issue - package unavailable in RHEL 7.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, rhel, rhel7

I am a novice to the yum installations. I need to install pip, python flask and python flask-restful in my server. I am using RHEL 7.5 and python version 3.6.8. When I try installing any modules. I get below errors. PFB

```
[root@testserver ~]# sudo yum install python3-pip

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
```

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Nothing to do

```
[root@testserver ~]# yum install python3-pip3

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
```

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

No package python3-pip3 available.

I tried running yum update. But same error. Please guide me here.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure software collections repos are enabled. See https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel/